# Laravel - Get Uploaded File URL to AJAX Modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I was curious how I would get the full url for a file if I'm pulling the data through AJAX via a get request.

At the moment, my successfully pulled data pulls the following:

```
$('#attachmentIDdetails').html(
    '<strong>'+data.attachmentTitle+'</strong><br>Description: '+data.attachmentBody+'<br>Date '+data.attachmentDate +'<br>Type: '+data.attachmentType +'<br>Visibility: '+data.attachmentVisibility + '<br>Uploaded by: '+data.user_id+'<br><a href="'+data.attachmentPath+'">Download Attachment</a><br><img width="100%" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center='+data.attachmentLat+',+'+data.attachmentLong+'&zoom=13&scale=1&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&key=MYSECRETKEY&format=png&visual_refresh=true&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0xff0000%7Clabel:%7C'+data.attachmentLat+',+'+data.attachmentLong+'" alt="Google Map of '+data.attachmentLat+',+'+data.attachmentLong+'">' );
}
```

If you look, one feature is my: data.attachmentPath - this is just the filename however. It's in a folder titled "shipments" under the storage folder. So how would I go about pulling the full URL for a download link?

Here is my controller code that the ajax call requests:

```
public function attachmentDetails(Request $request)
{
    return Shipment_Attachment::findOrFail($request->attachmentID); 
}
```

Comment: Can you show your current controller code?

Comment: I've updated to include the portion that is specific to this request, if you want the whole controller just let me know. Thanks! :)

Comment: For laravel you can use the `Storage::url();` function if you have run `php artisan storage:link` according to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem).

Comment: This means you'll be able to run `Storage::url('/shipments/' . $attachment_url)`

Comment: I have updated my two comments according to what I actually used in my project. The Storage facade is better for that.

Comment: @Phiter, how would I translate into a result from an AJAX request like I showed above? That is the portion I'm getting stuck at and can't seem to get past.

Comment: you'll have to send the full URL from the controller or have a js function that gets this base url on page load.

Comment: @Phiter, do you have any suggestions in code for my predicament. My issue is that a modal with details pops up with dynamic fields, so the attachment is technically always changing. So say if someone clicks the href for attachment 1, the modal window pops up, displaying the details of attachment 1, along with a download link. Same thing with if the user clicked on the href for attachment 2, where the same modal window would pop up and instead display the details from attachment 2 and a link to download 2. So I assume we'd have to go with the controller way, but I'm not sure how to pass...

Comment: ....that on to the AJAX portion of my script